# How to show loading page while another page is loading [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I do [this](http://vladimir.in/) with Angular. I wana show full page with animation while another page is loading and when that page is loaded I wana display...

**Edit:**

Also I have controller, I need to wait to conroller is loaded... And after controller is loaded and html added to page I need to remove loading page and show content.

```
 .controller('CommentsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
              $scope.param = $routeParams.id;
              $scope.comments = [];
              $http.get("/api/comments/"+ $scope.param)
              .success(function(data){
               //GET ALL USER AND COMMENTS TOGETHER
               $.each(data,function(index,value){
                   if(value.user){
                    $.each(value.user,function(index1,value1){
                        var new_object = $.extend({}, value, value1);
                        $scope.comments.push(new_object);

                    });
                   }
               });
});
```

**End Edit**

Here is my try but it will not wait till full page load It will just wait till get req is finished...

Any idea?

```
angular.module('loading')
        .directive('loading', loading);


function loading($http) {
    var loadingSniper = {
        link: link,
        restrict: "AE"
    };

    return loadingSniper;

    function link(scope, elm, attrs)
    {
        scope.isLoading = function () {
//            console.log('Remaining: ' + $http.pendingRequests.length);
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        };

        scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
        {
            if (v) {
                elm.show();
            } else {
                elm.hide();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you define a full page load? You can start more requests even from your controller bootstrapping code. It might require custom event handling to signal when the page loaded.

Comment: It's just loading sniper on page and nothing else... Check example I put.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define a custom directive, you can use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak). Take a look at this [great turorial about ngCloak](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/21).

This directive will hide the attributed elements when angular finished all the compilation of directives.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .splash {}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- The splash screen must be first -->
    <div id="splash" ng-cloak>
      <h2>Loading</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- The rest of our app -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

You have some asynchronous task initiated in the controller code. Don't forget an asynchronous task can be
a $http request (as in your case) or any code waiting or running on a WebWorker. That's why there is no
generic solution. In this case I recommend you to introduce a state variable in the scope. It will even
allow you to have multiple loader placeholders (For example separate loader for comments, news, gallery,
whatever).

You can remove the loader element when finished loading using ngIf:

```
...
<!-- The splash screen must be first -->
<div id="splash" ng-if="!loaded_comments">
  <h2>Loading</h2>
</div>
<!-- The rest of our app -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MainController">
</div>
...
```

js:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.loaded_comments = false; // <======== Setup initial state here
});

app.controller('CommentsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
  $scope.param = $routeParams.id;
  $scope.comments = [];
  $http.get("/api/comments/"+ $scope.param).success(function(data) {
    $rootScope.loaded_comments = true; // <======== set loaded state explicitly.

    //GET ALL USER AND COMMENTS TOGETHER
    $.each(data,function(index,value){
      if(value.user){
        $.each(value.user,function(index1,value1){
          var new_object = $.extend({}, value, value1);
          $scope.comments.push(new_object);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That is nice solution, but I still have problem... Splash screen finish but content still not loaded on page. Please check my update on main question.